# go struct items inline or each by line

Tags: go, struct

In [Go](https://golang.org/), when creating a struct what is the difference between grouping / adding items inline, for example:

```golang
type Item struct {
    a, b, c uint32
    d       uint32
}
```

Versus declaring items one by line, something like:

```golang
type Item struct {
    a uint32
    b uint32
    c uint32
    d uint32
}
```

Is just a matter of how items are represented.

What would be considered as the best practice to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference, the 2 types are identical.

To verify, see this example:

```
a := struct {
    a, b, c uint32
    d       uint32
}{}

b := struct {
    a uint32
    b uint32
    c uint32
    d uint32
}{}

fmt.Printf("%T\n%T\n", a, b)
fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(a) == reflect.TypeOf(b))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Y2WKIdMI82)):

```
struct { a uint32; b uint32; c uint32; d uint32 }
struct { a uint32; b uint32; c uint32; d uint32 }
true
```

You may put multiple fields in the same line to group fields that logically belong together, for example:

```
type City struct {
    Name     string
    lat, lon float64
}

type Point struct {
    X, Y   float64
    Weight float64
    Color  color.Color
}
```

Quoting from [Spec: Struct types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

> A struct is a **sequence** of named elements, called fields, each of which has a **name** and a **type**.

3 things that define the struct, all which will be the same if the only thing you change is the "number" of lines you put them:

1. Order will be the same (sequence)
2. Name will be the same
3. Type will be the same

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Just choose whatever is easier to read for you.